# Correct character encoding when calling BIRT using Java Bridge in PHP

Tags: java, php, character-encoding, birt, php-java-bridge

I'm calling BIRT to generate a PDF report via Java Bridge:

```
<?php

require_once("java/Java.inc");

class runReport {

    function runReport($report, $param, $output) {

        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$output.".pdf");

        $report_name = RP_REPORT . $report;
        $ctx = java_context()->getServletContext();
        $birtReportEngine = java("org.eclipse.birt.php.birtengine.BirtEngine")->getBirtEngine($ctx);
        java_context()->onShutdown(java("org.eclipse.birt.php.birtengine.BirtEngine")->getShutdownHook());

        try{

            $connect = new Java("connectDb");

            $report = $birtReportEngine->openReportDesign($report_name);
            $task = $birtReportEngine->createRunAndRenderTask($report);

            foreach ($param as $key => $value) {
                $task->setParameterValue($key, new java("java.lang.String",$value));
            }

            $taskOptions = new java("org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.PDFRenderOption");
            $outputStream = new java("java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream");
            $taskOptions->setOutputStream($outputStream);
            $taskOptions->setOutputFormat("pdf");

            $task->setRenderOption( $taskOptions );
            $task->getAppContext()->put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", $connect->getConnection(SERVEUR, BDD_PORT, BDD, LOGIN_DB, PWS_DB));
            $task->run();
            $task->close();


        } catch (JavaException $e) {

            echo $e; //"Error Calling BIRT";
        }

        echo java_values($outputStream->toByteArray());

    }
}
?>
```

This works fine unless `$param` contains parameters that contain non-ASCII characters. When `$param` does contain parameters that contain non-ASCII characters, no report is generated.

The encoding of `$param` is unknown.

Comment: Are you saying that when `$birtReportEngine->openReportDesign($report_name);` contains non-ASCII, the result doesn't get returned to the screen? Do you get a 500 error instead?

Comment: when the parameter sent to BIRT contains non-ASCII then I cannot open the pdf file.

Comment: and `$report_name` is a filename? So when the filename contains non-ASCII chars?

Comment: `$report_name` is a filename of the BIRT report having .rptdesign extension , the issue happens even if this filename has all ASCII chars.

Comment: But you've stated "accentuated letters then the report cannot be opened"!? "Accentuated" are non-ASCII. Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry I was not clear , so the issue is caused when the report `parameter` has accentuated letters.

Comment: What sets `$report`. Posted form? DB?

Comment: `$report` is the BIRT design filename , but the parameter is sent via the `$param` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default encoding of Java Bridge is "utf-8". Therefore strings need to be encoded to UTF-8.

```
foreach ($param as $key => $value) {
            $utf_8_value = mb_convert_encoding($report_name, "utf-8")
            $task->setParameterValue($key, new java("java.lang.String", $utf_8_value));
        }
```

If the elements of `$param` are not `iso-8895-1` encoded, set the third option of `mb_convert_encoding` to the appropriate encoding

Comment: there is no problem with the `$report_name` but with the `$param` argument.

Comment: Please see my update, which encodes the elements of `$param`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using UTF—8 use latin_swedish

Comment: where should I specify it ? can you provide a code ?

Comment: At the top you add: default_charset();

Comment: I modified the header code by this `header("Content-type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8");` but the report cannot be opened !

Comment: @TechnicCoder2000, I assume by the use of "latin_swedish", that you think it's a MySQL related issue? If so, I think you've got the wrong end of the stick

Comment: Sure... idk really know what you ment, so i wanted to be nice and try to find a correct answer